# Pywebview blocks flask app unless I open two webviews

Tags: python, flask, webview, python-multithreading

I built a python desktop webapp with a fairly simple flask backend which I'm currently serving simply through Chrome. I'm trying to package it using pywebview, but I ran into an intestesting roadblock.

I have code that looks like this in the main file of my package:

```
import os
import sys
from flasher import app

import httplib

import webview
import threading


def start_prod_server():
    runserver(debug=False, reloader=False)

def start_gui():
    webview.create_window("MyAppName", "http://localhost:5000", height=1000)

def runserver(debug=True, reloader=False):
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    url = "http://localhost:{}".format(port)

    print("ready!")
    app.run(host='::', port=port, debug=debug, use_reloader=reloader)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=start_prod_server)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    # This never works
    threading.Timer(1.5, start_gui).start()

    sys.exit()
```

This fails almost systematically, the window shows up blank and the backend doesn't respond to anything (including requests from a separate desktop browser).

I discovered accidentally that if I start two webview threads, it always works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=start_prod_server)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    # This works every time
    threading.Timer(1.5, start_gui).start()
    threading.Timer(1.5, start_gui).start()

    sys.exit()
```

What could be causing this? My understanding of threading in Python is fairly limited, so I'm not sure where to look. Is this likely to be a bug in pywebview, or am I doing something wrong with my threads?

I'm also open to suggestions of alternatives for the webview part, but I want to keep the python/flask part since the app already works fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bit of digging, I think I found the solution myself.

For whatever reason, `webview.create_window()` wasn't navigating to the page and getting stuck. Opening up the second window was causing both windows to navigate to the url and allowing the app to continue. (I still haven't understood why)

The problem is solved simply by adding `webview.load_url("http://localhost:5000")` like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=start_prod_server)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    threading.Timer(1.5, start_gui).start()
    webview.load_url("http://localhost:5000")

    sys.exit()
```

Any insight as to why this happens is still welcome though... In the source for pywebview, the two methods are making the exact same call to `self.browser.web_browser.Navigate(url)`